# Google Analytics API - pagination

Tags: ruby, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am downloading some data from Google Analytics using Google Api Client for Ruby (my Gemfile.lock sais its google-api-client (0.6.4)). I get data from google but it is so much of it that it comes (or at least it should) in few pages (more than 1000 rows).

I tried to use example from google (part of my code below)

```
    request = {
      :api_method => analytics.data.ga.get, 
      :parameters => {
        'ids' => "ga:" + ids, 
        'start-date' => start_date, 
        'end-date' => end_date, 
        'dimensions' => dimensions, 
        'metrics' => metrics,
        'max-results' => 10 #only for testing
      }
    }

    loop do
      result = api.execute(request)
      results << result

      break unless result.next_page_token
      request = result.next_page
    end
```

Well... it doesnt work.

```
result.next_page_token #returns always nil
```

I am using Analytics API (v3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also gone through same thing make it work with following code

```
     loop do
        result = api.execute(request)
        results << result
        next_page_uri = result.data.next_link
        break unless next_page_uri
        next_page = result.next_page
        next_page.uri = next_page_uri
        request = next_page
      end
```

Hope this will help to them who is facing same problem